# put user inputted word inside 2d array in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, user-input

I'm having a real difficult time trying to enter user's inputted words inside the 2d array.
What my program needs to do is create a word search puzzle that prompts user for how many words he or she will want to find, and what the given words are going to be. What I'm having trouble with is that I can't seem to put the user's input inside the 2d array. Below is my current code:

```
 public static void generate(){
      int rows = 5;
      int columns = 5;
      char[][] table = new char [rows][columns];
      int numberwanted;

      System.out.println("Type in the number of words you want to generate: ");
      numberwanted = userinput.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Type in the words you want to generate: ");
      for (int i = 0; i < numberwanted; i++){
         String words = userinput.next();
         char te = words.charAt(i);
         for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++){
            for(int c = 0; c < columns; c++){
               table[r][c] = te;
               System.out.print(table[r][c] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
         }

      }// forloop
```

The output:

```
Type in the number of words you want to generate: 
2
Type in the words you want to generate: 
test
t t t t t 
t t t t t 
t t t t t 
t t t t t 
t t t t t
```

goal output:

```
Type in the number of words you want to generate: 
2
Type in the words you want to generate: 
test
hi
t e s t x          x x t x x
x x x x x    or    x x e x x   and so on... with x's being empty
x h x x x          x x s x x 
x i x x x          x x t x x
x x x x x          x x h i x
```

Comment: `char te = words.charAt(i);`, you´re only setting the first letter for each word in the first iteration where you want to input the words. How do you think this will get every possible character in there, when you affectivly only do this once per input?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tweaked the whole program a bit to make it more robust. How it works now:

- process each row of the `table`.
- if the user wanted to provide a word, ask for the word.
- add the word (perhaps truncated) to the current `row`.
- right pad the row with `x` if needed.

At last, render the whole `table`.

```
private static int ROWS = 5;
private static int COLUMNS = 5;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[][] table = new char[ROWS][COLUMNS];
    int numberwanted;
    try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        System.out.println("Type in the number of words you want to generate: ");
        numberwanted = Math.min(in.nextInt(), ROWS);

        for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
            String word = null;
            if (row < numberwanted) {
                System.out.println(String.format("Type in the %d. word: ", row));
                word = in.next();
            }
            for (int col = 0; col < COLUMNS; col++) {
                table[row][col] = word != null && word.length() > col ? word.charAt(col) : 'x';
            }
        }
    }
    renderGrid(table);
}

private static void renderGrid(char[][] grid) {
    for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < COLUMNS; col++) {
            System.out.print(grid[row][col] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, for this part: word != null && word.length() > col ? word.charAt(col) : 'x'; could you explain to me what ? means or represents? never seen it before.

Comment: It means: if the word was retrieved from the user (value would be not `null`) and the word provides a character for the current column (`word.length > col`) then (`?`) obtain the character from the word at index col (`word.charAt(col)`). Otherwise (`:`) use `x`. Its Javas [ternary operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to update all the characters in the string. In your case you just have the first character of the string.

```
    public static void generate(){
          int rows = 5;
          int columns = 5;
          char[][] table = new char [rows][columns];
          int numberwanted;
          Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("Type in the number of words you want to generate: ");
          numberwanted = sc.nextInt();
          System.out.println("Type in the words you want to generate: ");
          int j=0;
          for (int i = 0; i < numberwanted; i++){
             String words = sc.next();
             char te = ' ';
             for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++){
                for(int c = 0; c < columns; c++){
                    if(j<words.length()) te = words.charAt(j++);
                    else te = '*';
                   table[r][c] = te;
                   System.out.print(table[r][c] + " ");

                }
                System.out.println();
             }

          }
}
```

**Update.
Also if you want only the diagonal elements. Here is it**

```
public static void generate(){
          int rows = 5;
          int columns = 5;
          char[][] table = new char [rows][columns];
          int numberwanted;
          Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("Type in the number of words you want to generate: ");
          numberwanted = sc.nextInt();
          System.out.println("Type in the words you want to generate: ");
          int j=0;
          for (int i = 0; i < numberwanted; i++){
             String words = sc.next();
             char te = ' ';
             for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++){
                for(int c = 0; c < columns; c++){
                    if(j<words.length() && r==c) te = words.charAt(j++);
                    else te = '*';
                   table[r][c] = te;
                   System.out.print(table[r][c] + " ");

                }
                System.out.println();
             }

          }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Provide the explanation of you solution.

Comment: See this in your code  -   char te = words.charAt(i); But you have change the character at i-th position everytime......So i added if(j<words.length()) te = words.charAt(j++);
                    else te = '*';       So that character at i-th changes